# Export Azure Network Security Group Rules to CSV using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I'm currently finishing up setting up our Azure network Security Groups and trying to find better ways to maintain our rules.  I Have a script for azure powershell to create the security rules via CSV but wanted to export.  When running the following command

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "name" -Detailed | export-Csv c:/file.csv
```

I get the file but it doesn't give me the details to csv.  It acts as if it ignores the -Detailed command.  Anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying NSG on subnet level and NOT on VM level this will surely help you. Firstly find out the nsg name using-

```
$nsgName = (Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupForSubnet -VirtualNetworkName "MYNetwork" -SubnetName "MySubnet").Name
```

Now use the nsg name to find out the detailed NGS details-

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgName -Detailed | Export-csv -path "C:\nsgfile.csv"
```

Output of above command on console-
[image]

[Updated answer]

Comment: this only exports out the subnet and doesn't export out the actual rules.   The headers are only Rules Name Location Label.

Comment: I believe you nsg are not in place thats why it's not pulling the proper output. First check nsg is in place and properly applied. Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupForSubnet -VirtualNetworkName "MYNetwork" -SubnetName "MySubnet"

Comment: isn't that the same thing as using the same script I used above? Your just creating a NSG group manually.

Comment: I am not creating a new nsg here. I am just pulling the nsg name first and then pulling the details. If NSG itself is not there it will pull the details for you else it will throw an error.

Comment: Can you reread my original question?  That is the exact command i'm having troubles with.

Comment: Well. The command is correct only. Thats why I am requesting you to re-check the name of nsg which is input parameter here. May be nsg name is there but there is no rule applied thats why it is not producing the output desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
(Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "name" -Detailed).Rules | Export-csv -path "C:\nsgfile.csv"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: please add some explanation in answer to raise the quality of your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can run below script to get all of NSGs and all of their rules in one single CSV :

```
 $azNsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup 

foreach ( $azNsg in $azNsgs ) {
    # custom rules
    Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $azNsg | `
        Select-Object @{label = 'NSG Name'; expression = { $azNsg.Name } }, `
        @{label = 'NSG Location'; expression = { $azNsg.Location } }, `
        @{label = 'Rule Name'; expression = { $_.Name } }, `
        @{label = 'Source'; expression = { $_.SourceAddressPrefix } }, `
        @{label = 'Source Application Security Group'; expression = { $_.SourceApplicationSecurityGroups.id.Split('/')[-1] } },
        @{label = 'Source Port Range'; expression = { $_.SourcePortRange } }, Access, Priority, Direction, `
        @{label = 'Destination'; expression = { $_.DestinationAddressPrefix } }, `
        @{label = 'Destination Application Security Group'; expression = { $_.DestinationApplicationSecurityGroups.id.Split('/')[-1] } }, `
        @{label = 'Destination Port Range'; expression = { $_.DestinationPortRange } }, `
        @{label = 'Resource Group Name'; expression = { $azNsg.ResourceGroupName } } | `
        Export-Csv -Path "$($home)\tf\nsg-rules.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append -force
    
    #  default rules
    Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $azNsg -Defaultrules | `
        Select-Object @{label = 'NSG Name'; expression = { $azNsg.Name } }, `
        @{label = 'NSG Location'; expression = { $azNsg.Location } }, `
        @{label = 'Rule Name'; expression = { $_.Name } }, `
        @{label = 'Source'; expression = { $_.SourceAddressPrefix } }, `
        @{label = 'Source Port Range'; expression = { $_.SourcePortRange } }, Access, Priority, Direction, `
        @{label = 'Destination'; expression = { $_.DestinationAddressPrefix } }, `
        @{label = 'Destination Port Range'; expression = { $_.DestinationPortRange } }, `
        @{label = 'Resource Group Name'; expression = { $azNsg.ResourceGroupName } } | `
        Export-Csv -Path "$($home)\tf\nsg-rules.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append -force
       
  
}
```